# Issue with Spring Boot 3 Spring Session: @EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession annotation sets the default value for Redis namespace

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-redis, spring-session

When I tried to use Redis indexing to solve the issue of concurrent control in Spring Security session clustering, I noticed that after adding the `@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession` annotation, Spring Session did not use the namespace configuration specified in the `application.yml` file (`spring.session.redis.namespace`), but instead used the default value specified in the `@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession` annotation.
I would like to know how to configure it so that the namespace uses the configuration from the `application.yml` file when using `@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession`.

To ensure that the namespace used in the `@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession` annotation is the same as the one configured in the `application.yml` file, I directly assign the redisNamespace parameter of the annotation with the value from the configuration file, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#using-a-different-namespace

You will find out that is as easy as this:

`@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession(redisNamespace = "${spring.session.redis.namespace}")`